# Wired "like" a dual transformer

Tags: furnace, thermostat-c-wire

I'm trying to update to a smart thermostat and my current one is wired like a dual transformer but I only have a single hvac system in the basement. Any idea why?

My plan is to move the blackwire from the R and put it on the C and have that as my C wire. I'm not an expert so just making sure the existing system was wired this way for  a reason (other than not knowing what to do with an extra wire and jumping RH/RC)

[image: thermostat]
[image: air handler]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess, but some thermostats require power to be delivered to Rc and Rh.  They will usually come with a jumper wire to bridge the Rc and Rh terminals, but maybe this installer just got into the habit of using two wires because that thermostat didn't come with a jumper or it was lost, or that's just how he liked it.

There should be no reason that both wires are used, and you should be able to use the black wire for the C wire.  Blue is typically used, but your thermostat wire doesn't have a white so your colors aren't going to match no matter what you do.

Comment: I would use black for W, and tape it with white tape, so you are at standard colors. You'll thank me later :)